# How to change data bases in the same page with select?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a project with PHP and conection PDO

I want to make a database change with ajax. I use a selector to update my page.

Image of combo box:

[image]

Then when I change the option in the combo box you must choose another database on the same server.

It occurred to me to change the host ip of the database configuration file, this is the code:

```
class conection extends PDO { 
public $typebd = 'mysql';
public $host = '192.168.1.2';
public $namebd = 'dbname';
public user = 'root';
public $pass = '1234'; 
public function __construct() {

try{
parent::__construct
($this->typebd.':host='.$this->host.';dbname='.$this->namebd, $this->user, $this->pass);
}catch(PDOException $e){
echo 'error Detail: ' . $e->getMessage();
     exit;
  }
}  
 public function setHost($varhost){
  $this->host = $varhost;
 }

 public function getHost(){
  return $this->host;
 }

 }
```

What I did was to change the host ip with a setter.
It works very well because with the getter I can see the change, the problem is that the code does not change because the constructor is present.

Just change the host ip, but not the connection

What should I do?

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code directly into the question.

Comment: It's not possible to swap a host inside PDO object: it represents a resource - a connection already made by the given host (passed in dsn string). What you should look into is swapping the connection itself - but it's hard to provide a better way without knowing specific use-cases.

Comment: raina77ow How could I make a change between data bases in the same page?